# Requirements on connecting to https

Tags: ios, ssl, https, afnetworking

I'm trying to connect using AFNetworking to API that is under https address. I keep getting 404 since the old app, based on ASIHTTPRequest is able to connect.

Do I have to implement certificate file into app somehow? What else should be provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have to add nothing, you only need to add http basic auth credentials if needed. This is how i usually connect to a https api with http basic auth.

```
//Base URL
NSURL *requestPasswordURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BASEURL];
//Http client with server credentials
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:requestURL];
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"user" password:@"password"];

//Set request parameters for example email
NSDictionary *params = @{@"email": email};
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:API_REQUEST parameters:params];
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;

//Prepare request
AFHTTPRequestOperation *request = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[requestPasswordOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //Your code
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Your Code
}];

//call start on your request operation
[request start];
```

Comment: Wel I'm doing that. What would be to blame if API returns 404 to me?

Comment: Actually info is a bit longer but not very helpful. Part of it: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404" UserInfo=0x9fa4670 .... then some more, and request link which seems correct

Comment: Eh, stupid question, did you change your URL string to https? Log the exact URL you are requesting, paste that into a browser, and see what you get. 404 means no file exists at that URL; it shouldn't mean any problem with encryption or authentication.

Comment: url is fine. It's https not http

Comment: did you check for typos? debugg the request block...error, request, etc.